# What are the different types of RFID shields for cards? (Some seem to block 1 side only, some affects all nearby cards regardless of side, etc.)

Tags: rfid

I'm new to RFID blocking and find it interesting. I came across this video to learn more and just have 2 questions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKwJwOm3bfI

Why would Vaultcard ([4:42](https://youtu.be/NKwJwOm3bfI?t=281)-5:30) protect both sides while Antetoko ([8:47](https://youtu.be/NKwJwOm3bfI?t=527)-9:20) protects one side? Are there different types of shields I need to be aware of?

If my intention is to create a DIY wallet with this setup:

```
Scannable card #1 |SHIELD| Card to protect |SHIELD| Scannable card #2
```

Is there a specific type of RFID Shield I should look for? one that doesn't 'jam' all nearby cards, as I want card #1 #2 to be functional? Is there a term for that for an easy further google search?

Comment: You appear to be confusing a card that is ***designed*** to block on one side with a card that is ***poorly implemented*** and has a weakness. You cannot conclude that one card is a different "type".

Comment: Anytime I see these questions I have to add: there is plenty of evidence that "electronic pickpocketing" is not actually a thing yet.  Out of all the ways your credit card can be stolen, this one is probably the very last one, right before "telepaths reading your mind to steal your credit card details".  Save your money and don't buy any.

Comment: @ConorMancone there are some (anonymous & unconfirmed) reports laying about that say Government actors are tracking people with this technology... its flimsy and weak. but it is something to be aware about.  for when it ever does change it to a creditable story.

Comment: @LvB I call B.S. on that.  It's far easier and more effective to track people using facial recognition, which governments actually *are* doing.  Sometimes the real conspiracy is much worse...

Comment: @ConorMancone it might be BS I did not add all those things about not creditable for no reason... however the reason stated was to track specific individuals over a longer distance (say 100 Meters) in a foreign country. where camera access is most likely harder to get in advance. i must also stress it was just 1 of the things used.. for state Level actors I would worry about a lot more than just there tracking my cards...

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want to do, I would not use an active blocking device like your video shows. I would use a blocking sleeve for the cards you want to protect.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I see, so RFID blocking devices are programmable to achieve different results?

Or are they all actually meant to scramble nearby cards, and the ones that only blocks 1 side is simply not working properly?

Comment: They are not programmable.

Answer (score 1):

An RFID shield is just a metal mesh or metal sheet. This acts as a mirror for electromagnetic (EM) radiation, in the same way the door and walls of microwave ovens reflects and confine the EM waves inside, preventing them from escaping and cooking stuff outside the oven. This also prevents outside EM from getting inside. Technically, this is called a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).

Since the RFID wavelengths are far bigger than the thickness of the cards, you only have two sides to shield instead of the six sides of an oven.

Because the power of RFID signal is so low, if you want to build a RIFD shield yourself, you can just take some aluminium foil (the same used in cooking) and wrap it around your RFID card. You can make it prettier by gluing it to some harder surface, like cardboard or leather.